# WebClient How to flush part of received data?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I want to implement partial flushing of the received content. For example, I have the handler:

```
return client
    .post()
    .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(
        request.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())))
    .exchange()
    .....
```

How to force flushing when some amount of databuffers is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a word of warning about this:

- by default (i.e. if you don't flush manually), Netty will buffer bytes and flush them from time to time, whenever the channel is ready and the flushing strategy thinks it's convenient. This is optimized for performance.
- if you wish to flush manually, it does not provide a guarantee that the other side will receive those groups of bytes the same way; intermediaries might buffer things along the way. This is where this might not achieve what you're trying to do: manual flushing is usually not about performance optimization, but protocol semantics.
- using a manual flushing strategy is only useful if you pair it with protocol semantics (like a message separator) so that the other side knows how to split messages (this is what Spring WebFlux is doing for SSE and `application/streaming+json`.

Now to implement that, Reactor provides several `windowXYZ` operators with different strategies. `Flux.window(int)` is based on the number of elements, `windowTimeout(Duration)` based on a duration, and others. In this case, you'll probably want to use `windowUntil(Predicate)`.

Let's try to implement something that flushes when a certain amount of data has been buffered.

```
Flux<DataBuffer> buffers = //...;

int maxSize = //...;
AtomicInteger currentSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
Flux<Flux<DataBuffer>> bufferWindow = buffers.windowUntil(buf -> {
    if (currentSize.addAndGet(buf.readableByteCount()) < maxSize) {
        return false;
    }
    currentSize.set(0);
    return true;
});

WebClient.create()
        .post()
        .body((outputMessage, context) -> outputMessage.writeAndFlushWith(bufferWindow))
        .retrieve();
```

Note that implementation **is flawed** if you're operating on an infinite stream of data: this won't flush until the quota is reached or the source is completed. So this might hold onto data for more time than necessary.

Comment: Your example is counting bytes. I don't want to link with the number of bytes, and I can limit max size of the buffer at the netty customization options. I want to flush after every 5'th received buffer. is it possible to achieve this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Already mentioned in my answer, it's the `window(int)` operator

Comment: @BrianClozel does the `writeAndFlushWith` work only for client posting to server? Can the server also send the same way to the client as the response.? I am not talking about SSE. I have super large byte[]. I would like to use the same way from server to client. But it does not seem to happen. The `serverWebExchange.getResponse().writeAndFlushWith(..)` seems to collect all the data and only then it sends